# Clojure into-array iterate over array

Tags: java, arrays, clojure, lisp

Im trying to make the change to Clojure from a primarily Java only experience and i am trying to solve a problem in Clojure.  I can do it in Java and it shouldnt be too much harder to convert to Clojure but i just cannot see how it would work....

What i want to do is iterate over an array of strings and then for ever string put into a map, my pseudo code is below but looks alot like Java

```
      private static void putToMap(String w) 
      {
        String thisw = getthisw(w);
        if (!map.containsKey(thisw)) 
        {
          map.put(thisw, w); 
          map.add(w);
        } 
      }

      private static String getthisw(String w) 
      {
        char [] wArray = w.toLowerCase().toCwarArray();
        Arrays.sort(wArray);
        return new String(wArray);
      }
```

This is how i am trying to do it in Clojure but im not sure how i would get data from the array that is given in the output if there is any?

The output i get from running what i have is this....   How would i use this to iterate over??  if so how would i use the array im given??

```
#<String[] [Ljava.lang.String;@790da477>
```

My Clojure functions....

```
(def strings '["one" "two" "three" "four" "five" ])

(defn sort [strings]
  (into-array String strings))
```

Example of input:

```
Array of Strings ["ONE"] ["TWO"] ["THREE"] ["FOUR"] ["FIVE"]
```

Example of output:

```
Map with strings converted to lowercase "one" "two" "three" "four" "five"
```

Comment: Your pseudocode is incomprehensible. Try writing what you want to do in actual Java, or any well-defined language, and ideally with an example input and desired output; that should be plenty for someone to show you how to do it in Clojure.

Comment: Updated my question to actual java code which i know works, i just have trouble converting to clojure

Comment: My fully working Java solution im trying to convert... http://pastebin.com/aRRdMCn4

Comment: Your [Java code in PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/aRRdMCn4) does not compile. It is missing a class header and a couple of data declarations. This is unacceptable.

Answer (score 3):

It really is tough to say exactly what you want here, but it seems you are thinking in the Java way.  A simple `map` will convert your strings into a list of their lower-case counterparts.

```
(def strings ["ONE" "TWO" "THREE" "FOUR" "FIVE"])

(defn convert [strings]
  (prn (map clojure.string/lower-case strings)))
```

Then you can call it in your REPL and get:

```
user=> (convert strings)
("one" "two" "three" "four" "five")
```